# Inserting an array of json to hasura

Tags: javascript, postgresql, graphql, hasura

I am trying to insert an array of objects to my hasura table. I have defined my columns like the image below

[image: Table Columns]

But I am receiving `malformed array literal: \"[]\"` error. I am using JSON.stringify from my client side code to stringify my array before calling the mutation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but shouldn't you need to use `JSON.parse` on your data before using it ?

Comment: Hasura(GraphQL) expects variables to be string `"message": "A string is expected for type: _json"`

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend that you just make the column a `jsonb` and then store the array directly. jsonb querying capabilities are significantly improved over json and Hasura doesn't have the greatest support for array columns (of any type).

When submitting data to an array column with Hasura it expects to receive it as a string using the PG array literal syntax, eg `'{1, 2, 3}'` for an int[] column.

Comment: and how would this look like for an array of objects?